# How to efficiently store data in Ionic local storage without converting object each time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

Every time we need to store an object we need to do a `JSON.stringify`.

Is there a efficient way to do this in `Ionic` and `AngularJS`?

The code that I am using is:

```
$window.localStorage[key] = value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to do the above is to create a `factory` and then access it:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var yourApp = angular.module('yourApp');

    yourApp.factory('$localStorage', ['$window', function($window) {
          return {
                store: function(key, value) {
                  $window.localStorage[key] = value;
                },
                get: function(key, defaultValue) {
                  return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
                },
                storeObject: function(key, value) {
                  $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
                },
                getObject: function(key,defaultValue) {
                  return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue);
                }
              }
            }])
})()
```

Then it can be used in the controller like:

```
(function(){
   var app = angular.module('yourApp');
   var appCtrl = app.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

   appCtrl.$inject = ['$localStorage'];

   function appCtrl($localStorage){
       $localStorage.get("yourVariable");
       $localStorage.getObject("yourObject");

       $localStorage.set("yourVariable");
       $localStorage.setObject(yourObject); //can be a JSON object

   }
 })()
```